# How To Identify Leaflet's Marker during 'popupopen/'dblclick ' event?(_source not working)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I tried this following source code:

```
    map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
         var identifyMarker= e.popupopen._source;
});
```

I just referred some guides from other sources that _source can identify the marker.
But when I run this source code, there is an error which is came from "_source".
So is there any other ways to identify leaflet's marker? Is it _source is not compatible with current version?

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the doc, [Marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker) has a getPopup() while [Popup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup) does not have a getMarker()

When you bind the popup to a marker, you have to keep this information in the popup object.

```
var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]);
var popup = L.popup().setContent("blabla");
var popup.marker = marker;
marker.bindPopup(popup);
```

The you can get access to the marker in the popupopen event (note e.popup and NOT e.popupopen)

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
         var identifyMarker = e.popup.marker;
});
```